# Tomcat: Error 404. The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists

Tags: java, spring, ubuntu, tomcat, war

I am very new to the server configuration topic.
I have developed my own site on Spring MVC and I want it to be on the server.
I bought VPS with Ubuntu and I have set Tomcat and phpMyAdmin up here.
I have packaged my Spring project as WAR by adding

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

to pom.xml.

I also have

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

in my pom.xml.

In Tomcat I chose my WAR file for deploy and deployed it.

But when I'm trying to enter my site (ip:port/MyWARName/) it shows

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZN3Ev.png)

Please, save me. I will answer all the questions needed for finding root of the problem.

Solutions that I found are not effective because they are saying that I misspelled something in my URL, but there is nothing to misspell because I'm trying to get to my "/" mapping.
That's how my "/" GetMapping looks like

```
@GetMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "redirect:/products/";
    }
```

In fact non of my mappings work.
[mapping 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7HaU.png)
[mapping 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQz6O.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That's f****** amazing! Looks like Tomcat v10+ doesn't support Spring boot anymore! I just switched to 8.5 and it works! Thank you, Apache, for wasting my 2 days of life!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).